# Migration from SAS UNIX to WINDOWS Environment

Tags: unix, sas

At present my SAS EG is in UNIX environment. But my dataset & codes are in local windows. So even though I can access dataset & codes from local windows, I can't run the codes in SAS Server as I can't create library in Windows environment, which I need to create to store output datasets.So is there any mechanism through which I can connect these 2 platforms so that I can run the SAS programmes from EG on SAS Server?

Just to give an example while running a program in EG to access Window PC: If I'm using the command:

libname folder "c:\folder\folder_a";

This library is not being created. No error is showing, but showing "library FOLDER doesnot exists".

I want to know why this is happing & what's the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: SAS EG is Windows-only client application, should be running on your PC. The SAS (application) server is probably running on Windows server since you mention incompatibility to Unix. Where is the data? What is located on Unix? ANother SAS installation?

Comment: The data is in windows environment & I need to run the codes in SAS in Unix environment.

Comment: So on Windows, there's no SAS installation.? Just output data should end up on Windows PC? And all input data on Unix?

Comment: yes. The output data should be in Window PC. So when I'm running the SAS I need to create library in Window PC so that all the data can be stored there. I can also create all output data in Unix environment & then download it into PC. But that's not my idea. Thanks Vasja!

Comment: If there's just EG installed on your PC and no SAS installed on your PC, your EG is probably connected to your Unix server. So when you run some program, it runs on Unix, where's no folder c:\folder\folder_a.

Comment: Yes. My EG installed in PC & no SAS installed in PC. So I can run the SAS & it run in UNIX environment only. So the entire output is stored in EG only (i.e. UNIX environment), which I've to download to PC (in order to distribute). But I want output to form in PC only so that I don't have to download them to my PC. I tried ur answer, but unfortunately it didn't work. Interesting thing is that I can access data  from my PC. So my PC is connected to my EG. But when I specify the same path, the command is not running. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you'll have to create output data on Unix SAS server, preferably in SAS on Windows representation, and then download the files to Windows (in order to distribute it?).

To produce SAS datasets in other than native host representation - Unix in your case - use OUTREP libname or dataset option.
Your libname should look like this:

```
libname windata "/sasdata/windata" OUTREP=WINDOWS_32;/* or WINDOWS_64"/
```

so that the data are native in format  native to SAS on Windows.

Than, you should be able to download the files via tools like WinSCP or something similar.

If you don't want to do it this way, you'll have to make a Windows directory accessible to the SAS process running on Unix as shared folder. That's actually not a SAS specific task.

You'll have to mount the windows share from Unix - probably something like http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/access-windows-shares-from-linux/ or 
http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/14769-how-can-i-view-windows-2003-folder-unix.html will help you, depending on what tool is available in your environment.
Once the share is mounted to Unix, just make a libname into the mounted directory as described above.

Comment: Thanks vasja for keep on trying to help me.